# automatically generate thumbnail images for documents (via screenshots?)

Tags: screenshot, thumbnail

I have to send reports to internal staff.

1. These reports will be sent via email (Outlook for the most part).
2. New reports are sent out daily.

The standard solution would be to send an HTML formatted email. If we had only one or two reports this would not be a problem -  but there are a lot of reports, each with a different format. And, as we're using Outlook everything must be in tables and we have to use inline styles. Yukk.

As it happens we are not sending the ENTIRE report in the email. We're only sending the cover page and the users will then click to go to the company intranet and view the complete report there.

One solution that would work (we tested it) would be to take a screenshot (Windows - PRTSC; Snag-It), crop it and then paste that in an email.

So the question is: Is there a software which could be part of the following process:

1. System runs batch job
2. HTTP request calls file
3. Take Screen-shot (jpg); Crop-Screenshot
4. Save screen shot

   Repeat steps 2-4
5. Send emails with images

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Your title is very misleading, because it has nothing to do with screenshots. You probably meant 'snapshots', but you will have to give a much better description of the data you will have to send: "that day's data" and "lots of reports in a diferent format" is too vague. What kind of data formats, where is its source? Also: what OS, price? Read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: And do you really have to convert everything into an HTML email formatted email without attachments? Than your actual issue is how to do that, not how to send email. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: @JanDoggen - I mean a screenshot (a jpg).

Comment: @Mayo To clarify your question, are you looking for a software recommendation that can perform as many of steps 1-5 as possible?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - I have steps 1,2 and 5.  I can call a chron job, and send out an HTML formatted email with the required data. It would be very time consuming to write the table based HTML for the email. However if a "screenshot" can be taken, saved as a jpg and then insert the img src into the email then "VOILA" business people are happy and we don't spend weeks writing table based layouts. (There are a LOT of reports.)

Comment: Then you only need 3 & 4 - something that you can run from the command line (as a cron job) to take a screenshot of a given URL ... "webkit2png is a command line tool that creates screenshots of webpages" http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/ is for Linux (which I am inferring from your mention of a cron job). I am sure that there is a Windows equivalent, if needed)

Comment: @Mawg - Thx a lot. Will take a closer look at it later on today.

Comment: @Mawg - It's perfect. You should make that an answer so I can vote you up.

Comment: If you are taking screenshots of a program with lots of white/monochromatic areas, or text, you might prefer to use png instead of jpg. Text will look clearer and the image will be more lightweight. Jpg is preferrable only if you have lots of actual photos in it (unlikely).

Comment: @Agostino - You're correct a .png would be better than a .jpg; and the image is, except for graphs and the logo, entirely text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in a comment above, "I have steps 1,2 and 5.

Then you only need 3 & 4 - something that you can run from the command line (as a cron job) to take a screenshot of a given URL ...

"[webkit2png](http://paulhammond.org/webkit2png) is a command line tool that creates screenshots of webpages".

The program is for Linux (which I am inferring from your mention of a cron job). I am sure that there is a Windows equivalent, if needed)